# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in going over array

Tags: php

The code below...

```
$msgArr = split("\n", $message);
$newMsg = "";
foreach ($msgArr as $msg){
    if (trim(end(split(":", $msg))) != '')
        $newMsg .= $msg . "\r\n";
}
```

Seems to generate the error: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/siteurl/public_html/questionnaire/full_questionnaire_submitted.php on line 1033

Any ideas why this is?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following strict standards, you should only pass a variable to `end()` not a function return value directly. This is because `end()` consumes it's argument by reference. (Check @NiettheDarkAbsol's nice explanation)

This line:

```
if (trim(end(split(":", $msg))) != '')
```

should be:

```
$pieces = split(":", $msg);
if (trim(end($pieces)) !== '')
```

Answer (score 1):

The end function moves the cursor of the array you pass as parameter, in your case you pass the return of split, witch can't be passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

[`end()`](http://php.net/end) has the following signature:

```
mixed end ( array &$array )
```

So it takes a reference as its argument. References work by pointing to a variable, rather than copying the variable's value (as would normally be the case), which means you cannot directly pass a function's return value to it, hence the error.

PHP has been programmed to handle this kind of thing gracefully, since it's a simple matter of creating an internal, temporary variable, so it will continue to work but you will get the Strict Standards error.

Since you want to get the trimmed text from the last `:` to the end of the string, consider:

```
$lastpiece = trim(substr(strrchr($msg,":"),1));
```

This uses [`strrchr`](http://php.net/strrchr) to get everything from the last `:` to the end, `substr` to knock off that last `:`, before finally `trim`ming it.